# При чтении файла в андроид получаю исключение Exception access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/" is denied

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Ситуация такая. Мне надо перенести файл сохранений своей бесплатной игры в папку с платной игрой. Т.е. я должен прочитать файл из чужой папки и создать и записать в файл в своей папке. Если создавать читать файл в своей папке все хорошо. А при попытке считать файл из чужой папки получаю исключение:  `Exception access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/..." is denied`
Можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: Никак, приложения не могут получать доступ к данным друг друга, иначе любое приложение могло бы украсть токен например сбербанка и ограбить пользователя. Но обойти конечно можно через повышение привелегий, например сделать приложение администратором устройства, как делают мобильные антивирусы.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно сделать как бы общую папку для приложений, чтобы она была доступна для всех, ну для первого и второго приложения?

Comment: Можно наверное, но для этого вы должны быть разработчиком обоих приложений, чтобы внести изменения в код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если вкратце это не возможно. Но я нашел обходной вариант, я сделал общую папку сохранений для своих игр:

```
private void createPuths()
    {
        string pathFrom = Application.persistentDataPath;
        string pattern = @"/Android\/data\/net\.lalalala\.gamename\/files";
        string target = "";
    
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        pathFrom = regex.Replace(pathFrom, target);
        folder = pathFrom + folder;
        pathToAnotherConfig = folder + gameConfigsFile;
        pathToAnotherProgress = folder + gameProgressFile;
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        if (!dirInfo.Exists)
        {
            dirInfo.Create();
        }

    }
```